# How to have a basic html structure?

Tags: html, visual-studio-code

I saw there is a method to load the HTML sample in VS Code.

But I don't know what is the shortcut of it.
[image]
[image]

Comment: maybe try `ctrl` + `space`

Comment: Yes, the same operation!

Comment: Here's the link to all the shortcuts that would be useful. 
https://docs.emmet.io/cheat-sheet/

Answer (score 16, accepted):

`! + Enter` would do the work for you.

Answer (score 3):

type ! at the beginning and hit enter it will generate the basic HTML Structure i do it all the time

Answer (score 1):

press CTRL+! and then press Tab or press ctrl + space

Answer (score 1):

Another approach is to install extension
https://github.com/sidthesloth92/vsc_html5_boilerplate

it will generate this code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--[if lt IE 7]>      <html class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8 lt-ie7"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7]>         <html class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8]>         <html class="no-js lt-ie9"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if gt IE 8]><!--> <html class="no-js"> <!--<![endif]-->
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <title></title>
        <meta name="description" content="">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="">
    </head>
    <body>
        <!--[if lt IE 7]>
            <p class="browsehappy">You are using an <strong>outdated</strong> browser. Please <a href="#">upgrade your browser</a> to improve your experience.</p>
        <![endif]-->

        <script src="" async defer></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: who uses Internet Explorer <v9 anymore?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using windows
[simply check the language if it is HTML or not and afterward the same step shift+!.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GYiR8.png).

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31373560)

Answer (score -1):

`! + Enter` will give you the basic HTML structure.

Comment: Why would you post exactly the same answer as already-existing answers, but then three years later?